# Best SEO URL Structure : Filter product list by multiple tags

Tags: seo, wordpress, url, tags, filtering

Which url is better for SEO (google)?

separate tags like sub folders with slash "/":

```
1) shop.com/product-category-1/tags/product-tag-1/product-tag-2
```

separate with characters plus "+" underscore "_" tilde"~" comma ",":

```
2) shop.com/product-category-1/tags/product-tag-1+product-tag-2
3) shop.com/product-category-1/tags/product-tag-1_product-tag-2
4) shop.com/product-category-1/tags/product-tag-1,product-tag-2
5) shop.com/product-category-1/product-tag-1,product-tag-2
```

in query string (GET variables):

```
6) shop.com/product-category-1?tags=product-tag-1,product-tag-2
7) shop.com/product-category-1?tags[]=product-tag-1&tags[]=product-tag-2
```

for example, WordPress uses Options 2 and 4 But those pages use `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX">` to not index by Google! I know that Google hates all characters except dash "-" :(

Which url will be indexed by Google better?(1-7) OR Any new idea?

Comment: These questions have been asked about a thousand ways here before. Google does not hate certain characters, however, they do have special meanings. Of your options, #1 is the most effective and traditional. Why? Because this follows the oldest of convention and has real semantic meaning. Mixing conventions confuses things. Stick with simple. Simple always works best. Cheers!!

Comment: "Google does not hate certain characters" -- except that an underscore in a URL is not a word separator to Google.  Google wants searches for programming variables with underscores to come up with the whole variable name only, so they have never treated an underscore in a URL as a word separator.   If you use an underscore Google won't be able to highlight words in the URL in bold in the search results, nor assign any weight to the fact that you use them in the URL.   Not that Google gives much of any weight to words in URLs right now anyway.

Comment: The bigger problem is making these URLs available to search engines at all.  There are several problems.   Product list pages are low quality to begin with.  Now you are going to have tag combinations with an exponential number of URLs all with low quality and duplicate content.   There is no way that Google is going to index many of these pages and your entire site is going to look low quality because of it.

Comment: I always say don't reinvent the wheel if it's not needed. Looking around at the top sites in the world is generally a good way of practice in terms of URL structure and so on. Stack Exchange sites use `+` in their URLs with infinite possibilities well almost. Since multiple tag pages are accessible using the 'search' function, Google is not aware of these pages until someone backlinks to those pages.

Comment: So, if you allow users to find articles based on multiple selections or type input then Google isn't going to know they exist unless you include them in your sitemap which personally I wouldn't bother. Google can then reward you and index those multiple tag pages if someone backlinks to those pages.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller *...except that an underscore in a URL is...* [insert cheese eating grin] *...however, they do have special meanings.* I just was not going to get into details. It has been a while since I thought about this subject. Google does understand the terms using an underscore, however, believes the intent is that they be taken as connected in some fashion. Like you say, similar to variables. Perfectly valid assumption. Cheers!!

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I don' think separators are required nowadays since many CMS systems create urls without hyphens or underscores and Google/Bing have no problem establishing words combined all together so it would seem odd it wouldn't understand if they used a symbol.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller ... I think I've solved "**duplicate content**" problem so:
 1. Do not index URLs with more than 3 tags.(put `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX">`)
 2- Arrangement of tags is important. (for example:
  `shop.com/product-cat-1/prod-tag-1+prod-tag-2 ==> go to page`
  `shop.com/product-cat-1/prod-tag-2+prod-tag-1 ==> go to 404 not found!`
 Because for each tag, priority is defined.)
-----------
What do you think of this new method?
Define categories as tags (Merge categories and tags):
 `shop.com/products/tag-1/tag-2/tag-3...`

Comment: I'd noindex pages with more than one tag.  Maybe even noindex all tag pages altogether if products can be found in other ways on your site such as categories.